# Custom colorbar not showing colors correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

First time posting on SE, trying my best with formatting, behaviour and such.

I'm trying to create a stand-alone colorbar, to use next to a image. I want to have 10 discrete colors, that I define in my custom colormap. Why does not TikZ use these 10-rgb colors in the colorbar? It seems to interpolate in between and apply some shading.

I want it to look like this:
[image]

But it ends up looking like this:[image]
I have used MS Paint to find the RGB-colors of the colorbar. Why are they now showing as the RGB-colors I entered? My code is below.

```
\pgfplotsset{
    % define the custom colormap
    colormap={my colormap}{
        rgb255=(0,0,255),
        rgb255=(0, 100, 255),
        rgb255=(0, 160, 255),
        rgb255=(0, 210, 255),
        rgb255=(0, 255, 255),
        rgb255=(0, 255, 0),
        rgb255=(0, 255, 255),
        rgb255=(0, 255, 200),
        rgb255=(0, 255, 200),
        rgb255=(255, 0  ,0),
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        hide axis,
        scale only axis,
        height=0pt,
        width=0pt,
        colormap name=my colormap,
        colorbar sampled,
        colorbar horizontal,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=1,
        colorbar style={
            xlabel={Relative density},
            samples=11,
            height=0.5cm,
            width=10cm,
            xtick style={
                color=black}
            },
    ]
        \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks, Johan

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! If you want someone to help you, you should post a complete [minimal working example MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) beginning at `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, including all packages and commands necessary to compile your code and create the issue.

Comment: You aren't specifying the colour map correctly.

Comment: I understand. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RGB Values that you add are wrong. And you have to add `colormap access=piecewise const` otherwise the colour displayed is dependent on the colours defined before and after it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    % define the custom colormap
    colormap={my colormap}{
        rgb255=(0, 0, 255),
        rgb255=(10, 100, 255),
        rgb255=(20, 160, 255),
        rgb255=(30, 210, 255),
        rgb255=(30, 255, 255),
        rgb255=(30, 255, 40),
        rgb255=(255, 255, 50),
        rgb255=(255, 200, 50),
        rgb255=(255, 120, 40),
        rgb255=(255, 0, 0),
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        hide axis,
        scale only axis,
        height=0pt,
        width=0pt,
        colormap name=my colormap,
        colorbar sampled,
        colormap access=piecewise const, % add this
        colorbar horizontal,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=1,
        colorbar style={
            xlabel={Relative density},
            samples=11,
            height=0.5cm,
            width=10cm,
            xtick style={
                color=black}
            },
    ]
        \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Just to demonstrate it lets look at

```
\pgfplotsset{
    colormap={my colormap}{
        rgb255=(0, 0, 0),
        rgb255=(255, 255, 255),
    },
}
```

Where the first block should be black and the second white.

[image]

Comment: What was the mistake in the code of the OP?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It was just the wrong RGB Values and nothing Tex related.

Comment: You can comment out the line `colormap name=my colormap,`.

Comment: Which seems odd. I guess defining it also activates it. The commas in the colormap specification don't seem to match the syntax in the manual. Or am I looking at the wrong case? (It just uses spaces for simple maps.)

Comment: The colorbar I want to achieve has its last cell completely red, i.e an RGB code of (255,0,0) which I added. Your last cell has (255,30,30), but even if I change it to what I want it's not the right shade of red. Do I misinterpret how a colormap works perhaps? My thinking is the 10 colors I define in my colormap will be the 10  I see in the colorbar.

Comment: @Johan Yes you are right the colours are wrong. They seam to be influenced by what colour is defined before and after the cell. But I don't know why.

Comment: @Johan fixed it.